# Vue Router does not render correct component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have the some nested routes in `vue-router`, which can be found in `router.js`. However, everytime I logged the user in, the `Query` and `Result` link in the `Header` always render `Register` and `Login` components, but I can confirmed that my `Vuex` has the proper token setup by investigating through **vue developer tools**.

---

So my expectation for the `vue-router` to work is as followed:

1. User attempt to login at `/user/login`
2. Login successfully, token set in `Vuex` state
3. User is redirected to `/`
4. User click on `/query` or `result` links, `<router-view>` render `Query` or `Result` component in `App.vue`.
5. User click on `Logout` button, `Vuex` state is cleared.
6. User is redirected back to `/user/login`.

But the result I get is:

1. User attempt to login at `/user/login`
2. Login successfully, token set in `Vuex` state
3. User is redirected to `/`
4. User click on `/query` link, `<router-view>` in `App.vue` rendered `Register` component.
5. User click on `/result` link, `<router-view>` in `App.vue` rendered `Login` component.
6. User refresh the page using `F5`.
7. User click on `/query` or `result` links, `<router-view>` render `Query` or `Result` component in `App.vue`.
8. User click on `Logout` button, `Vuex` state is cleared.
9. User is redirected back to `/user/login`.
10. User click on `Login` button, `<router-view>` in `App.vue` rendered `Result` component.

---

### What I have tried

1. Remove the token protection on route, the `<router-view>` still does not render the correct components.
2. Remove `v-if="auth"` from all `<router-link>` with token protection still on, the problem seems to go away. But I wanted to render `Query` and `Result` only when the user logged in, and vice versa.
3. Use `v-show` instead of `v-if` remove the issue, but I doubt it is a proper way to hide the links from the user.
4. Name all routes, but the problem still persists.

### Some Code

This is my `router.js`

```
import User from './components/user/User'
import Home from './components/Home'
import Login from './components/user/Login'
import Register from './components/user/Register'
import Query from './components/Query'
import Result from './components/result/Result'
import List from './components/result/List'
import Display from './components/result/Display'

import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = [
    {
        path: '/', name: 'home', component: Home
    },
    {
        path: '/user', component: User, children: [
            {path: 'login', component: Login},
            {path: 'register', component: Register},
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '/query', name: 'query', component: Query
    },
    {
        path: '/result', component: Result, children: [
            {path: '', component: List},
            {path: ':token', component: Display}
        ]
    },
    {path: '*', redirect: '/'},
];

export default new VueRouter({
    routes: router,
    mode: 'history',
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
        if (savedPosition) {
            return savedPosition;
        }
        if (to.hash) {
            return {selector: to.hash};
        }
        return {x: 0, y: 0};
    }
})
```

This is my `Header.vue`

```
<template>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" id="header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CMAP</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <router-link to="/user/register" active-class="active" tag="li" v-if="!auth">
                    <a class="nav-link">Register</a>
                </router-link>
                <router-link to="/user/login" active-class="active" tag="li" v-if="!auth">
                    <a class="nav-link">Login</a>
                </router-link>
                <router-link to="/query" active-class="active" tag="li" v-if="auth">
                    <a class="nav-link">Query</a>
                </router-link>
                <router-link to="/result" active-class="active" tag="li" v-if="auth">
                    <a class="nav-link">Result</a>
                </router-link>
                <li @click="logout" class="nav-item" v-if="auth">
                    <a class="nav-link">Logout</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</template>

<script>
    import * as  types from '../../stores/types'

    export default {
        methods: {
            logout() {
                // clear state.token and redirect user to '/user/login'
                this.$store.dispatch(types.ACTION_USER_LOGOUT);
            }
        },
        computed: {
            auth() {
                // return true if state.token is set in vuex
                return this.$store.getters[types.GETTER_IS_AUTHENTICATED]
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is my `App.vue`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <appHeader></appHeader>
        <div class="container">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
        <appFooter></appFooter>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Header from './components/layouts/Header'
    import Footer from './components/layouts/Footer'

    export default {
        components: {
            'appHeader': Header,
            'appFooter': Footer
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is my `store/store.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

import actions from './actions';
import getters from './getters';
import mutations from './mutations';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        jwt: {
          token: null,
          expire: null
        },      
    },
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions,
});
```

This is my `store/actions.js`

```
import * as types from './types';
import axios from '../axios';
import router from '../router'

export default {
    [types.ACTION_USER_LOGIN]: ({commit, dispatch}, payload) => {
        axios.post('/api/user/login/', {
            email: payload.email,
            password: payload.password,
        })
            .then(res => {
                if (Object.keys(res.data).length === 0 && res.data.constructor === Object) {
                    return
                }
                let payload = {
                    'token': res.data.token,
                    'expire': new Date(res.data.expire_on * 1000)
                };

                dispatch(types.ACTION_SET_TOKEN, payload);
                commit(types.MUTATE_UPDATE_JWT, payload);
                router.push('/')
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    },
    [types.ACTION_USER_REGISTER]: ({commit, dispatch}, payload) => {
        axios.post('/api/user/register/', {
            email: payload.email,
            password: payload.password
        }).then(res => {
            if (Object.keys(res.data).length === 0 && res.data.constructor === Object) {
                return
            }
            let payload = {
                'token': res.data.token,
                'expire': new Date(res.data.expire_on * 1000)
            };
            dispatch(types.ACTION_SET_TOKEN, payload);
            commit(types.MUTATE_UPDATE_JWT, payload);
            router.push('/')
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    },
    [types.ACTION_USER_LOGOUT]: ({commit, dispatch}) => {
        dispatch(types.ACTION_CLEAR_TOKEN);
        commit(types.MUTATE_CLEAR_AUTH);
        router.push("/user/login");
    },
    [types.ACTION_CLEAR_TOKEN]: () => {
        localStorage.removeItem('jwt_token');
        localStorage.removeItem('jwt_expire');
    },
    [types.ACTION_SET_TOKEN]: ({commit}, payload) => {
        localStorage.setItem("jwt_token", payload.token);
        localStorage.setItem("jwt_expire", payload.expire);
    }     
};
```

This is my `store/getters.js`

```
import * as types from './types';

export default {
    [types.GETTER_IS_AUTHENTICATED]: state => {
        return state.jwt.token !== null
    }
};
```

This is my `store/mutations.js`

import * as types from './types';

```
export default {
    [types.MUTATE_UPDATE_JWT]: (state, payload) => {
        state.jwt = payload
    },
    [types.MUTATE_CLEAR_AUTH]: (state) => {
        state.jwt.token = null;
        state.jwt.expire = null;
    },
};
```

This is my `axios.js` custom instance

```
import {store} from './stores/store'
import axios from 'axios'

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
    withCredentials: true
});

instance.interceptors.request.use(config => {
    if (store.state.jwt.token != null) {
        config.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + store.state.jwt.token;
    }
    return config;
});

export default instance
```

My `store/types.js` contains all the constant variable string, so I don't think it is necessary to include here.

Please let me know if I need to provide more information on the problem.

Comment: Of course you need - we do not see the Vuex store implementation.

Comment: @IVOGELOV, I have added my Vuex store implementation in the edit

Comment: Not sure its right but did you tried to name your routes in your router?

Comment: @OnurÖzkan I have tried to name all the route, but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by assigning a unique `key` to every `router-link` in `Header.vue`. So the final `Header.vue` file looks like this after modifications:

```
<template>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" id="header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CMAP</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <router-link to="/user/register" active-class="active" tag="li" v-if="!auth" key="link_reg">
                    <a class="nav-link">Register</a>
                </router-link>
                <router-link to="/user/login" active-class="active" tag="li" v-if="!auth" key="link_login">
                    <a class="nav-link">Login</a>
                </router-link>
                <router-link to="/query" active-class="active" tag="li" v-if="auth" key="link_query">
                    <a class="nav-link">Query</a>
                </router-link>
                <router-link to="/result" active-class="active" tag="li" v-if="auth" key="link_result">
                    <a class="nav-link">Result</a>
                </router-link>
                <li @click="logout" class="nav-item" v-if="auth">
                    <a class="nav-link">Logout</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</template>

<script>
    import * as  types from '../../stores/types'

    export default {
        methods: {
            logout() {
                // clear state.token and redirect user to '/user/login'
                this.$store.dispatch(types.ACTION_USER_LOGOUT);
            }
        },
        computed: {
            auth() {
                // return true if state.token is set in vuex
                return this.$store.getters[types.GETTER_IS_AUTHENTICATED]
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

It seems that VueJS couldn't update the DOM properly without associated key in each `v-if` for `router-link`.